# How to debug a "400 Bad Request" on iOS from Gmail app embedded Safari browser

Tags: ios, gmail, mobile-safari, web-developer-toolbar

We have a web form which we send out via email links, having particular issue with embedded safari web browser. I cannot share the link example at this time.

The error occurs when you open the link in the Gmail app on iOS and select the Safari option. This opens the Safari Web Browser embedded in Gmail. When submitting the web form you get a "400 Bad Request". If you copy the link, then go out of Gmail, open Safari web browser and paste the link, then submission of form works fine.

I would love to be able to debug that in developer tools.

Does anyone know how to do this? I know if you have a Mac (which I don't) then you can connect your Safari web browser to developer tools, does this work for the Gmail app embedded safari browser?

Answer (score 1):

In the end managed to debug by downloading and installing Proxyman iPhone app, which is able to capture HTTPS requests from all apps on the device. It works by installing a special VPN from the device to the app, and you have to generate and install a CA certificate. Proxyman is able to export HTTPS requests in cURL format which you can then use for debugging from a computer.

https://proxyman.io/

If you have a local development environment and network, connect iPhone to computer on local area network, and then you can use phone to trigger requests in development environment, but that can be tricky with HTTPS. So can use ngrok to route requests from internet to local environment.